# How to get proper breaks automaticallly for R plotting?

Tags: r, plot, r-grid

We all know R is very flexible in plotting, even without powerful packages. When I need to add grid to my plot, I use grid().

But if I don't specify the breaks, the lines don't really make sense as benchmark lines. Usually the breaks are sparse.

I am wondering whether it can be done automatically. For example:

If `range(y)==c(1,10);` then I hope the breaks will be `seq(1,10,by=1)`.

If `range(y)==c(0.2,0.8);` then I hope the breaks will be `seq(0.2,0.8,by=0.1)`.

If `range(y)==c(0.2,1000);` then I hope the breaks will be `seq(0,1000,by=100)`.

If `range(y)==c(988,1458);` then I hope the breaks will be `seq(1000,1500,by=100)`.

If `range(y)==c(-0.86,1.05);` then I hope the breaks will be `c(-0.7,-0.8, -0.9, ..., 0.9, 1.0, 1.1)`

The same purpose works for specifying the x-axis/y-axis labels, or using `abline()`. Any thoughts?

Comment: `ifelse` and `cut` might help you here.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I agree with you; however I would like to construct a function, which can be more compatible for any y, to find out the proper breaks automatically. The breaks can sometimes be decimals for few millions.